# Works in terminal but not in script

Tags: bash, perl, shell, shebang

```
pip install sphinx
sphinx-quickstart -q -p DSPackageDocs -a Me -v 1 --ext-autodoc
perl -i -e $'s/#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(\'.\'))/sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(\'.\/DSPackage\'))/g' conf.py
```

The 3rd line looks into a file and replaces some text. Specifically, I replace

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

with

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./DSPackage'))
```

This line works perfectly fine in the terminal in the shell script I get the error:

> Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: Do you use the same shell in the terminal and in the script?

Comment: Is the first line of the script `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: Which she-bang are you using, specify it explicitly as `bash`, i.e. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Adding #!/bin/sh doesn't change anything. Adding #!/bin/bash still fails that line but also fails my pip install commend. @choroba: I'm new to linux, but I think you are asking if I am running the script in the same terminal that I'm running the command? The answer is yes.

Comment: I didn't tell you to add `#!/bin/sh`. In fact, it's a potential source of problems, which is why I asked about it.

Comment: And no, choroba's question wasn't about terminals. What exactly is in your script file and how exactly are you running it?

Comment: Actually #! /bin/bash works! Maybe i typed it incorrectly before! AWESOME! THANKS!

Comment: @EdMorton Where I have perl it was originally sed, I changed it to perl during my troubleshooting, I never realized I didn't change it back to sed. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the error if I execute the command in `dash`. `dash` doesn't seem to support the `$'...'` quotes.

It works OK in `bash`, and emits different errors in `zsh` and `ksh`:

```
Unknown regexp modifier "/D" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/S" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/P" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/k" at -e line 1, at end of line
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Make sure to specify the correct shell on the first line of the script

```
#! /bin/bash
```

and to call the script correctly:

```
/path/to/the/script.sh
```

or

```
cd /path/to/the
./script.sh
```